# Remove unwanted lines and smooth CAPTCHA text

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, captcha, contour

I trying to get text Image from captcha image using opencv to build my dataset for training.My extracted captcha is not so smooth and optimized.Can someone help me to optimize and suggest the best method to remove the unwanted noise,and get the smooth captcha text.
Right now,i am first adding some padding, thresholding it and find the contours.

Issues:
1.adding padding using border_replicate may add some noise
2.thresholding is not smooth and perfect

Original Image :[image]
Threshold Image:[image]
Contour Image:[image]
desired Image/Result:[image]
final separated numbers required:
[image: 1]

code:

```
import os
import os.path
import cv2
import glob
import imutils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

CAPTCHA_IMAGE_FOLDER = "generated_captcha_images"
OUTPUT_FOLDER = "extracted_letter_images"


# Get a list of all the captcha images we need to process
captcha_image_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(CAPTCHA_IMAGE_FOLDER, "*"))
counts = {}

# loop over the image paths
for (i, captcha_image_file) in enumerate(captcha_image_files):
    print("[INFO] processing image {}/{}".format(i + 1, len(captcha_image_files)))

    # Since the filename contains the captcha text (i.e. "2A2X.png" has the text "2A2X"),
    # grab the base filename as the text
    filename = os.path.basename(captcha_image_file)
    captcha_correct_text = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

    # Load the image and convert it to grayscale
    image = cv2.imread(captcha_image_file)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Add some extra padding around the image
    gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray, 8, 8, 8, 8, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    # threshold the image (convert it to pure black and white)

    thresh = cv2.threshold(
        gray, 36, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

    # find the contours (continuous blobs of pixels) the image
    contours = cv2.findContours(
        thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Hack for compatibility with different OpenCV versions
    contours = contours[1] if imutils.is_cv3() else contours[0]
```

Comment: Not quite sure why you drew the contours, since you already have a pretty nice thresholded image not that far from the image you added as the desired result. Or did you expect that the contours themselves will look like that? (perhaps you should be  looking for a skeleton rether than contours)

Comment: @TLousky I am actually thresholding it first and then applying contour to get the individual continuous text and then traing the individual letter images to train my ml model.

Comment: new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364761/remove-unwanted-background-line-noise-from-captcha-using-opencv

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366098/how-to-erode-this-thresholded-image-using-opencv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You might be looking for a skeleton rather than contours here. Check out this [Skeletonize function in Scikit Image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html):

```
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
skeleton = skeletonize(thresh.astype(np.float32) / 255)

f, axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(10,6))
for ax, img, t in zip(axs, [thresh, skeleton], ['Thresholded Image', 'SKImage Skeleton']):
    ax.imshow( img, 'gray' )
    ax.set_title(t)
    ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I am actually thresholding it first and then applying contour to get the individual continuous text and then traing the individual letter images to train my ml model.
Can u suggest the best way to do this.If I use the my threshold image,it's quite thick and not continuous as u can see.The skeleton u obtained is good and quite sepratable but u can see the 4 is not clear as it should.would it be great if I seprate the numbers from original image somehow and get the sharpest and distinguished numbers possible?