# How to erode this thresholded image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, captcha, contour

I am trying to first remove the captcha numbers by thresholding and then eroding it ,to get slim continuous lines to get better output.
**Problem:the eroded image is not continuous as u can see**
Original Image:[image]
Threshold Image:(Here digits area is to thick,so i want it to be shrink,slim and continous)
[image]
my output:
[image]
Desired Output/Result wanted:
[image]

code:

```
import os
import os.path
import cv2
import glob
import imutils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
CAPTCHA_IMAGE_FOLDER = "generated_captcha_images"
OUTPUT_FOLDER = "extracted_letter_images"


# Get a list of all the captcha images we need to process
captcha_image_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(CAPTCHA_IMAGE_FOLDER, "*"))
counts = {}

# loop over the image paths
for (i, captcha_image_file) in enumerate(captcha_image_files):
    print("[INFO] processing image {}/{}".format(i + 1, len(captcha_image_files)))

    filename = os.path.basename(captcha_image_file)
    captcha_correct_text = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

    image = cv2.imread(captcha_image_file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(
        gray, 36, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
    erode = cv2.erode(thresh, np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8), iterations=1)
    plt.imshow(erode, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `skeleton` operation will work better

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

 
img = cv2.imread('/Users/alex/Downloads/fOrmgm.jpeg',0)

thinned = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(img)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
thinned = cv2.dilate(thinned, element) # this operation is optional

cv2.imshow("skeleton", thinned)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

---

**Update**
You can [find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33098888/820795) implementations of skeleton in python using morph operations. Result for me is not good. Probably you can filter this antennas.
[image]

Implementation of `cv2.ximgproc.thinning()` you can find [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/a26f71313009c93d105151094436eecd4a0990ed/modules/ximgproc/src/thinning.cpp).

Comment: Nice,image is little bit wavy but can be used.can we implement this in opencv-python rather than in opencv-contrib-python?I found this on a blog ( https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/skeletonization-in-python-using-opencv-b7fa16867331 ),but cant figure out a way to implement this for my image

Comment: @AyushYadav OpenCV's thinning/skeletonize algorithm is part of the contribution module; There's no implementation in the main module. Maybe you can morphologically approximate the algorithm using erosion and bitwise operations. Here's an implementation, but is written in C++: https://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/

Comment: @AyushYadav I've update answer